# make a network request, save the result, and pass the result into main class in react-native

Tags: react-native, request, fetch, state

Hi everyone i am new to react-native. I'm trying to make a network request, save the result, and pass the result into the main App.js class

```
import { Component } from "react";
class Utils extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
          data: " ",
        };
      }
        getSid(){
          try {
            fetch('https://help_me').
          then((response) =>response.json()).then((responseJson)=>{
            this.setState({ data: responseJson.sid });
          });
            
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } 
        }
     
  }
  const utils = new Utils();
  export default utils;
```

Now App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import utils from './Utils';
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      data: " ",    
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    utils.getSid()
  }

  render() {
    const { data} = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>      
              <Text>{utils.state.data}</Text> 
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

when I try to start the app, the device shows me a blank screen. because? then every time I create a new component (for example Utils.js) do I always have to specify its state? thanks a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one question, why not like this ? rather than Util class, directly in your comp?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import utils from './Utils';
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      data: " ",    
    };
  }

    getSid(){
          try {
            fetch('https://help_me').
          then((response) =>response.json()).then((responseJson)=>{
            this.setState({ data: responseJson.sid });
          });
            
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } 
        }

  componentDidMount() {
   getSid()
  }

  render() {
    const { data} = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>      
              <Text>{data}</Text> 
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

or why not a normal util function rather than class :

```
export const getSid = () => {
 try {
            fetch('https://help_me').
          then((response) =>response.json()).then((responseJson)=>{
            return responseJson
          });

          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } 
}
```

Comment: I wanted to create a Utils class to insert all network requests. But how do I get the values ​​resulting from a network request and recall them in the main class?

Comment: @Elly ill update the answer, give me 30 mins